# rpc.mountd is segfaulting immediately on launch

Tags: linux, nfs, segmentation-fault

After completing a routine `apt upgrade` on my server and laptop and rebooting everything, I found that

```
$ mount nfs-server:/mnt /mountpoint
```

was just hanging forever. There didn't seem to be any logical explanation why.

I first turned to Wireshark for insight:

```
140 60.439219227  192.168.0.2  192.168.0.3  NFS  170  V4 Reply (Call In 138) EXCHANGE_ID
141 60.439302740  192.168.0.3  192.168.0.2  NFS  258  V4 Call (Reply In 142) CREATE_SESSION
142 60.439984105  192.168.0.2  192.168.0.3  NFS  194  V4 Reply (Call In 141) CREATE_SESSION
143 60.440070415  192.168.0.3  192.168.0.2  NFS  198  V4 Call (Reply In 147) PUTROOTFH | GETATTR
147 65.511499058  192.168.0.2  192.168.0.3  NFS  158  V4 Reply (Call In 143) PUTROOTFH Status: NFS4ERR_DELAY
```

Huh. So it's kinda working, but something's not completely happy. What's the holdup?

I next turned to `dmesg`, which promptly moved me past the "go round in circles looking for clues indeterminately" stage, all at once:

```
[  283.998430] rpc.mountd[2238]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f816550f3d6 sp 00007ffd60245820 error 4 in libc-2.28.so[7f81654b7000+148000]
[  283.998523] Code: 1f 44 00 00 85 f6 0f 8e 88 00 00 00 83 fe 01 0f 84 8f 00 00 00 41 54 83 ee 01 49 89 fc 41 b8 01 00 00 00 55 b9 0a 00 00 00 53 <8b> 02 48 89 d3 89 c5 83 e0 df 89 02 48 63 d6 48 89 fe 48 89 df 83
```

That occurred almost immediately after startup. I wonder what's going on here...

How do I start this myself? Some digging around in unit files suggests it wants the `--manage-gids` argument, and squinting at `--help` mentions `-F` to run it in the foreground. Ok.

```
# rpc.mountd --manage-gids -F
rpc.mountd: Version 1.3.3 starting
Segmentation fault
```

Well that didn't take too long to reproduce! What justification does it have for doing that, then?!

```
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=37, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/mtab", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7faf15dd5168, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

...oh no, my system hasn't hosed itself, has it? :S

```
# ls -l /etc/mtab
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 12 15:17 /etc/mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts
```

...OK, whew.

Hmm. I'll bet that rogue `openat()` is actually coming from a library call. I wonder if `ltrace` adds any additional interesting context?

```
__xstat(1, "/", 0x7ffe45d9f620)   = 0
free(0)                           = <void>
strdup("/")                       = 0x559b3adaf640
strlen("/")                       = 1
setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r")       = 0
getmntent(0 <no return ...>
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Hrmmm, what are--

```
DESCRIPTION
       These routines are used  to  access  the  filesystem  description  file
       /etc/fstab and the mounted filesystem description file /etc/mtab.

       The setmntent() function opens the filesystem description file filename
       and returns a file pointer which can be used by getmntent().  The argu-
       ment  type  is the type of access required and can take the same values
       as the mode argument of fopen(3).

       The getmntent() function reads the next line of the filesystem descrip-
       tion  file  from stream and returns a pointer to a structure containing
       the broken out fields from a line in the file.  The pointer points to a
       static area of memory which is overwritten by subsequent calls to getm-
       ntent().

       ...

RETURN VALUE
       The getmntent() and getmntent_r() functions return a pointer to the mn-
       tent structure or NULL on failure.
```

Hang on: `setmntent()` is returning 0, aka a NULL pointer. And then that NULL pointer is being used in `getmntent()`. That sounds broken...?

I wonder what's really going on here. Wouldn't it be great if whatever package `rpc.mountd` is in, had debug symb... oh, awesome, `nfs-kernel-server-dbgsym` is a thing. Cool.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7db73d6 in __GI___fgets_unlocked (buf=buf@entry=0x5555555a8060 "", n=n@entry=4096, fp=fp@entry=0x0) at iofgets_u.c:50
50      iofgets_u.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7db73d6 in __GI___fgets_unlocked (buf=buf@entry=0x5555555a8060 "", n=n@entry=4096, fp=fp@entry=0x0) at iofgets_u.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7e2ef16 in __GI___getmntent_r (stream=stream@entry=0x0, mp=mp@entry=0x7ffff7efb140 , buffer=0x5555555a8060 "", bufsiz=bufsiz@entry=4096) at mntent_r.c:130
#2  0x00007ffff7e2ed03 in getmntent (stream=stream@entry=0x0) at mntent.c:52
#3  0x000055555555cfa8 in next_mnt (v=0x555555571ac8 , p=0x5555555a4ff8 "/") at cache.c:383
#4  nfsd_fh (f=6) at cache.c:736
#5  0x000055555555d2cd in cache_process_req (readfds=readfds@entry=0x7fffffffe960) at cache.c:1424
#6  0x000055555555d718 in my_svc_run () at svc_run.c:117
#7  0x0000555555558ee3 in main (argc=, argv=) at mountd.c:894
```

Hmm.

```
367  /* Iterate through /etc/mtab, finding mountpoints
368   * at or below a given path
369   */
370  static char *next_mnt(void **v, char *p)
371  {
372          FILE *f;
373          struct mntent *me;
374          size_t l = strlen(p);
375          if (*v == NULL) {
376                  f = setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r");
377                  *v = f;
378          } else
379                  f = *v;
380          while ((me = getmntent(f)) != NULL && l > 1 &&
381                 (strncmp(me->mnt_dir, p, l) != 0 ||
382                  me->mnt_dir[l] != '/'))
383                  ;
384          if (me == NULL) {
385                  endmntent(f);
386                  *v = NULL;
387                  return NULL;
388          }
389          return me->mnt_dir;
390  }
```

Hmmmmm.

So... `setmntent()` is returning NULL, that's being assigned to `f`, then `getmntent(f)` is... segfaulting...?

Let's have a look.

```
$ cat setmntent.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mntent.h>

int main() {
        FILE *ret = setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r");
        printf("%p\n", (void *)ret);
        return 0;
}

$ gcc -o setmntent setmntent.c

$ ./setmntent 
(nil)
```

Yay. So on my system, because `/etc/mtab` is a symlink, `setmntent()` asplodes. Great.

And let me guess...

```
$ cat getmntent.c
#include <mntent.h>

int main() {
        getmntent(NULL);
}

$ gcc -o getmntent getmntent.c

$ ./getmntent 
Segmentation fault
```

Well that's thoroughly logical, then. **Headdesk**

#### I just want NFS working. Wat do?

Comment: First piece of potential interestingness: my laptop, which uses ext4, and also has `/etc/mtab` symlinked to `../proc/self/mounts`, does not exhibit this problem with the `setmntent` test program. My server is however using ZFS. Something to potentially investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

### Horrible-ish workaround:

#### `rm /etc/mtab; cat /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab`

#### Caveat emptor:

#### This may randomly break things that expect `/etc/mtab` to never, ever go away for even a nanosecond

##### Probably don't use this to fix production without plenty of spare duct tape (time, resources) available

---

I'm not marking this (self-answer) accepted, because I consider it a hack. Rather, I seek other comments/answers discussing

- why my system has `/etc/mtab` pointing at `/proc/self/mounts`, given that this NFS issue seems 100% reproducible and whould theoretically(?) be blowing up everywhere
- why this is happening at all
- what I should do to do **canonically** fix this situation (particularly with configuring `/etc/mtab` sanely)

Such info would be highly appreciated!